# nim, how to get the result of multithreading execution immediately, without any delay?

Tags: threadpoolexecutor, nim-lang

I'm absolute beginner in Nim Lang.
I have been practicing python for the last 4 years, before that there was a sharp.

Nim is great, but I don't understand how to comprehend him yet.

I'm trying to figure out how to work with threading in Nim.
to do this, I wrote a template that receives the execution time, and procedure that perform some CPU bound work. In the console I see this result(for n=50):

```
Time threaded = 0.945 s
@[1, 26, 234, 1154, 3765, 9192, 18138, 30588, 45812, 62740, 80215, 97299, 113287, 127786, 140587, 151685, 161144, 169120, 175767, 181274, 185794, 189493, 192496, 194930, 196888, 198463, 199718, 200720, 201512, 202139, 202629, 203014, 203311, 203542, 203718, 203853, 203954, 204031, 204087, 204129, 204159, 204181, 204196, 204207, 204214, 204219, 204222, 204224, 204225, 204226]
```

but before `echo res` is executed(res is output to the console) i wait about ~11-12sec.
Why?

my split_into_terms.nim file code:

```
import sequtils, threadpool, times, strutils

template time(statement: untyped): float =
  let t0 = cpuTime()
  statement
  cpuTime() - t0

proc splitToTerms(n:int, k:int): seq[seq[int]] =

  var kk = k
  if kk == 0: kk = n

  if n == 0:
    return newSeq[seq[int]]()

  result = newSeq[seq[int]]()

  if n <= kk:
    result.add(@[n])

  for i in 1 .. min(n, kk):
    for l in splitToTerms(n-i, i):
      result.add(l&(@[i]))


var res: seq[int]

proc threaded(n:int) =
    for i in 1 .. n:
      let rs = spawn splitToTerms(n,i)
      res.add len(^rs)

let n=50

let t = time(threaded(n)).formatFloat(ffDecimal, precision = 3)
echo "Time threaded = ", t, " s"
echo res
```

and the compile&run command:

```
nim c -r -d:release -o:benchmark.sh --threads:on nimlang/split_into_terms.nim
```

Comment: running your code on a Mac M1 with Nim 1.6 I see what seems to me a correct time output: `Time threaded = 13.473 s`

Comment: ~12sec is correct for single thread execution(for me). 
full code:  https://codeshare.io/Qnrdeq

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with your code is that you're calling a blocking procedure (`^`) in the same loop you're spawning your threads, which means you're getting a consecutive execution.

Answer (score 1):

to expand upon @Zoom's answer:

in your example code, within each loop iteration you are:

`let rs = spawn splitToTerms(n,i)` <--spawning a thread

`res.add(^rs)` <--blocking until that thread finishes

Instead, you need to collect your `FlowVar`s, then query them, either as they finish, or after theyre all complete.

```
proc threaded(n:int) =
  var flowvars: seq[FlowVar[seq[seq[int]]]]
  for i in 1..n:
    flowvars.add spawn splitToTerms(n,i)
  sync() # wait for everything that's been spawned to finish
  for f in flowvars:
    res.add len(^f) # now collect the results
```

---

outside the question but additionally:

to help the nim compiler optimize your code, it helps not to have global variables so put the business code into a `main` proc

its not necessary to explicitly initialize the special `result` variable

your code spends a lot of time allocating many tiny seqs. changing `splitToTerms` to:

```
proc splitToTerms(n:int, k:int): seq[seq[int]] =
  if n == 0:
    return

  let kk = if k==0: n else: k
  
  if n <= kk:
    result.add(@[n])

  for i in 1 .. min(n, kk):
    var tmp = splitToTerms(n-i,i)
    for t in tmp.mitems:
      t.add i
    result.add tmp
```

gives me a 10-15% speedup

of course, for a completely unfair speedup, swap out `seq[seq[int]]` for `seq[set[int8]]`